# Creating a Stackplot in Julia Makie

Tags: plot, colors, julia, recipe, makie.jl

I tried to create a `@recipe` Stackplot in Julia Makie. This is my first attempt:

```
@recipe(MyPlot, x, y, z) do scene
    Theme(
        plot_color = :red
    )
end

function Makie.plot!(myplot::MyPlot)
    map(myplot[:x], myplot[:y]) do xs, ys
    cys= []
        for i in 1:length(ys)
            push!(cys,cumsum(ys[1:i])[end])  
        end
        for (x, y) in zip(xs, cys) 
        scatterlines!(myplot, x, y)
        band!(myplot, x, zero(y), y, color = (:red, 0.3))
        end

    end
    myplot  
end

myplot([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 7]])
```

The problem is I would like to create an area that starts at 0 and ends at y_1, another area that starts at y_1 and ends at y_2, and so on until y_n. Additionally, I would like to change the color so that the scatterlines are linked to the color of the area below it.

I tried playing with `:color`, but the problem is that every `scatterline!` and every `band!` has the same color.

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWMsV.png)